unknow keyword: :expires_in when deploy Ruby 3.2.2 application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk
When I try to deploy Ruby 3.2.2 application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk (Platform Ruby 3.2 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2023), I get below error:
[29074] unknown keyword: :expires_in
[29074] /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-client-0.22.2/lib/redis_client/config.rb:21:in `initialize'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-client-0.22.2/lib/redis_client/config.rb:207:in `initialize'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-client-0.22.2/lib/redis_client.rb:166:in `new'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-client-0.22.2/lib/redis_client.rb:166:in `config'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-5.2.0/lib/redis/client.rb:23:in `config'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-5.2.0/lib/redis.rb:142:in `initialize_client'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-5.2.0/lib/redis.rb:73:in `initialize'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-store-1.10.0/lib/redis/store.rb:21:in `initialize'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-store-1.10.0/lib/redis/store/factory.rb:27:in `new'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-store-1.10.0/lib/redis/store/factory.rb:27:in `create'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-store-1.10.0/lib/redis/store/factory.rb:10:in `create'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-activesupport-5.3.0/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:71:in `initialize'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.3/lib/active_support/cache.rb:94:in `new'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.3/lib/active_support/cache.rb:94:in `lookup_store'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.3/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:80:in `block in <module:Bootstrap>'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    /usr/share/ruby3.2/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    /usr/share/ruby3.2/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    /usr/share/ruby3.2/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    /usr/share/ruby3.2/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    /usr/share/ruby3.2/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    /usr/share/ruby3.2/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    /usr/share/ruby3.2/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    /usr/share/ruby3.2/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    /usr/share/ruby3.2/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.3/lib/rails/application.rb:426:in `initialize!'
    /var/app/current/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
    config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.11/lib/rack/builder.rb:103:in `eval'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.11/lib/rack/builder.rb:103:in `new_from_string'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.11/lib/rack/builder.rb:94:in `load_file'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.11/lib/rack/builder.rb:64:in `parse_file'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-6.4.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:368:in `load_rackup'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-6.4.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:290:in `app'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-6.4.2/lib/puma/runner.rb:173:in `app'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-6.4.2/lib/puma/runner.rb:177:in `start_server'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-6.4.2/lib/puma/cluster/worker.rb:60:in `run'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-6.4.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:216:in `worker'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-6.4.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:97:in `block in spawn_worker'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-6.4.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:97:in `fork'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-6.4.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:97:in `spawn_worker'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-6.4.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:81:in `block in spawn_workers'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-6.4.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:74:in `times'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-6.4.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:74:in `spawn_workers'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-6.4.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:173:in `check_workers'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-6.4.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:455:in `run'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-6.4.2/lib/puma/launcher.rb:194:in `run'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-6.4.2/lib/puma/cli.rb:75:in `run'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-6.4.2/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/bin/puma:25:in `load'
    /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/bin/puma:25:in `<main>'
[29074] Early termination of worker

The part that causes this error is in /config/environments/production.rb as:
 config.cache_store = :redis_store, "#{ENV["REDIS_URL"]}/1/cache", { expires_in: 90.minutes }

I couldn't find what is incorrect in this configuration setting. Can you please advise?

You are using the old and unmaintained redis-activesupport gem which likely conflicts with newer Rails versions. Instead, you should use Rails' builtin Redis cache store.

Thanks. In new version, I could not find expires_in parameter. Is there an example for that?

Cache eviction is done by Redis itself if configured correctly. See the above link to the Rails docs and https://redis.io/docs/latest/develop/reference/eviction/
